# Centering figure environment wider than textwidth (subfigures inside)

Tags: beamer, floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have 3 aligned subfigures that I would like to center, with a total horizontalsize larger than textwidth. Here is my code for now :

```
begin{figure}
        \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=1.2\textwidth}
        \captionsetup{font=scriptsize,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false, labelfont=scriptsize, labelformat=empty}
        \captionsetup[sub]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize, justification = centering, labelformat=empty}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.15m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L1_ep}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.05m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L3_ep}
            \end{subfigure} 
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.025m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L6_ep}
            \end{subfigure}     
            \caption{Fonction de courant - différentes solutions obtenues pour différents \\ rapport d'aspects de la montagne.} 
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure}
```

However, impossible to center all of this : I tried to use the center environment and also changing `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=1.2\textwidth}` to `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=1.2\textwidth, center}`.
Then, searching a bit on the net, I tried to put all of this inside :

```
\makebox[\textwidth][\side]{ }
```

leading to :

```
 \begin{frame}      
  \begin{figure}
        \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{
        \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=1.2\textwidth}
        \captionsetup{font=scriptsize,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false, labelfont=scriptsize, labelformat=empty}
        \captionsetup[sub]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize, justification = centering, labelformat=empty}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.15m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L1_ep}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.05m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L3_ep}
            \end{subfigure} 
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.0cm}  
                \caption{$H/L = 0.025m$}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bouss_L6_ep}
            \end{subfigure}     
            \caption{Fonction de courant - différentes solutions obtenues pour différents \\ rapport d'aspects de la montagne.} 
        \end{adjustbox}
        }
    \end{figure}        
    \end{frame}
```

But it raised an error : ! Undefined control sequence.
 \side
l.141 \end{frame}

Comment: Well, I’d say: of course!  What happens if you replace `\side` with `c`?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.